# What Rich text editor should I use for a custom CMS

Tags: dojo, tinymce, rte, rich-text-editor

I want to build a custom CMS where users a Rich text editor is the main way to create content rather than wiki markup.

Besides **stability** and **performance**, I want the RTE to be easily **extensible**. The latter point is very important because I intend to extend it to my needs.

For example I want the users to be able to embed OpenSocial gadgets and whiteboard (based on canvas) into the page. I also the want the users to embed media source like (youtube, slideshare etc).

My preliminary investigation shows that Dojo's (dijit) RTE and TinyMCE are pretty good. How would you compare the two in terms of stability, performance and extensibility. Any other RTE's I should be looking at that fit the bill?

PS: I am using dojo as the main js library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hava a look [here (blog post with some very helpfull informations)](http://disgruntleddevs.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/tinymce-and-dojo/).

My own opinion is that there are two free available rtes that are close to each other in comparison. Those are CKEditor and Tinymce. My experience lies on the tinymce side and i can say that the extensibility using own plugins is great with it. Some independent tests have shown that tinymce seems to be more adavanced than CKEditor, others claim CKEditor is better. You will have to decide on your own (development is advancing further each day and new functionality has been developed since those tests).

You may also have a look here for comparisons and discussions:

- http://verens.com/2007/09/27/fckeditor-vs-tinymce-vs-everything-else/
- http://verens.com/2007/09/27/fckeditor-vs-tinymce-vs-everything-else/
- http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/wysiwyg-shootout-and-winner